# How Can I Pop a message window when CentOS shutdown?

Tags: linux, centos, gtk, gnome

When the Centos will Shutdwon, reboot or logoff , I want to pop a Message Window.

I made the window by gtk, then how can i do?

Please forgive me my lousy English. :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to write your program as a daemon, and use DBus to monitor signals from [logind](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/logind/). Take a look at the `PrepareForShutdown` and `PrepareForSleep` signals; probably also one or more of the `UserRemoved`, `SessionRemoved`, `SeatRemoved` signals.

In order to pop up your dialog you will also need to set an [inhibitor](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/inhibit/) so that the system cannot shut down until your dialog box has been dismissed.

If you want to interrupt logging off or switching users, you will also need to set an [inhibitor on `org.gnome.SessionManager`](https://people.gnome.org/~mccann/gnome-session/docs/gnome-session.html#org.gnome.SessionManager.Inhibit).

Answer (score 0):

'Behind the scenes', in modern Linuxes, is a system which sends notifications to applications interested in them. Though I haven't used shutdown and similar events, I'm quite certain they are available too. This notification service is Window-manager independent, and works in both Gtk+ and Qt.

Even though CentOS isn't mentioned [in this list](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Desktop_notifications), there should be ample information in the links provided. Lower down the page is a reference to `libnotify`, which is the toolbox for `C`. Many others are mentioned.